# Comparing times (with milliseconds and without dates)

Tags: php, date, time

I'm parsing subtitle files (srt format) and here's an example of a line of dialogue:

```
27
00:01:32,400 --> 00:01:34,300
Maybe they came back
for Chinese food.
```

The times come in the format

```
hours:minutes:seconds,milliseconds
```

I want to manipulate these times and do comparisons but the various PHP classes I've come across don't seem to have support for milliseconds.

---

My problem:

One thing I want to do is parse 2 subtitle files that are for the same piece of media (e.g. same film, or same TV episode, etc.) and compare each subtitle file's text for the same lines of dialogue. The problem is that the start and end times for the same lines will be slightly off by a few hundred milliseconds. For example, taking the line above, in another subtitle file the time for that same line is

```
00:01:32,320 --> 00:01:34,160
```

To get both files' versions of the same line of dialogue, you could check to see if there is a line in file two that is within a few hundred milliseconds of file one's start and end times, and that should catch it. Something like that. So I need to manipulate times by adding milliseconds to them and also do comparisons of those times.

Comment: so what is the problem you have programming this? Is just converting the timestamp to all-milliseconds somehow not working? (00:01:32,320 is simply 320 + 32*1000 + 1*60*1000 + 0*3600*1000...)

Comment: I think the poster is looking at calculating fractions of seconds, so multiplying seconds by 1000 is not going to provide the precision needed. The PHP `microtime()` function is probably the best tool for accomplishing this.

Comment: What version PHP are you on?

Comment: but the times he lists are already in millisecond format... the system's microtime has nothing to do with this input conversion.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, very true. I guess I was thinking of a more abstracted approach, but you're correct that the times provided could very well be converted into milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you mike and zeantsoi, both of your solutions worked. I wish math came to me easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on PHP >=5.3 (required for `getTimestamp()`), this will work:

```
$unformatted_start = '00:01:32,400';
$unformatted_end = '00:01:34,300';

// Split into hh:mm:ss and milliseconds
$start_array = explode(',', $unformatted_start);
$end_array = explode(',', $unformatted_end);

// Convert hh:mm:ss to DateTime
$start  = new DateTime($start_array[0]);
$end = new DateTime($end_array[0]);

// Convert to time in seconds (PHP >=5.3 only)
$start_in_seconds = $start->getTimestamp();
$end_in_seconds = $end->getTimestamp();

// Convert to milliseconds, then add remaining milliseconds
$start_in_milliseconds = ($start_in_seconds * 1000) + $start_array[1];
$end_in_milliseconds = ($end_in_seconds * 1000) + $end_array[1];

// Calculate absolute value of the difference between start and end
$elapsed = abs($start_in_milliseconds - $end_in_milliseconds);

echo $elapsed; // 1900
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

```
if (strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date2)) { # date1 is after date2
    # do work here
} 
if (strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)) { #date2 is after date1
    # do other work here
}
```

Comment: Try the microtime function with a complete date.

Comment: I went with above solution.